# How to add and convert text to double from a textbox to an array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am attempting to write code for a simple calculator that will store up to 10 results in an array.

I have the calculator portion working correctly but I am having troubles storing and displaying the results from the array.

```
Public Class wk2_David_Thieme_vb
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim resultArray(9) As Double
Dim i As Integer = 0

Protected Sub btnStore_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStore.Click

    Dim Num As Double

    If i < 9 Then
        For i = 0 To resultArray.Length - 1
            Num = Convert.ToDouble(txtResult.Text)
            resultArray(i) = Num
            i += 1
        Next i
    Else
        txtResult.Text = "10 results already stored"
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    For i = 0 To UBound(resultArray)
        lstResults.Items.Add(resultArray(i).ToString())
    Next
End Sub
```

The results display 10 zeros in the listbox, no matter how what the user inputs into the calculator.  Also, it doesn't display the "10 results already stored" once 10 entries have been added to the array.  Thanks for any help you can provide, I am new to vb.net and am still learning, so please be gentle.

Comment: Your array list Will always be same to the last txtResult value

Comment: I believe that is because I need to include the code in the btnDisplay sub in a For loop, but the main issue at the moment is that the text from the user isn't loading into the array.  It always displays zero

Comment: First in btnStore_Click after you store the value you increment by 1 not with for loop, second your text muat be numeric

Comment: How about if you change your array to list of object?

Comment: I have tried all the suggestions and I really appreciate all the help, but the only thing that will display in the listbox is zeros, no matter what the txtResult box says.  Any suggestions why this is happening?  Thanks for anything you can come up with.

Comment: can you show the your last coding

Comment: I figured it out mostly.  The issue was that I didn't declare the array/counter right.  They needed to be public shared. '     Public Shared resultArray(9) As Double
    Public Shared i As Integer = 0'

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any For loop inside `btnSave_Click`. What a for loop does in your case is that it goes through all of items in your list and adds input number to your array. Instead you need to add each number separately to its own place in array.
To do that just change btnSave like below:

```
Dim doubleArray(9) As Double
Dim i As Integer = 0

Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim Num As Double

    If i < 10 Then
        doubleArray(i) = (If(Double.TryParse(txtResult.Text, Num), Num, 0))
        i += 1
    Else
        txtResult.Text = "10 results already stored"
    End If
End Sub
```

That way there is nothing wrong inside your `btnDisplay_Click`.

You can instead use a List to save results in it. Therefore you've to declare a List(Of Double) instead of double array. So `btnSave_Click` should be changed as below:

```
Dim listOfDouble As New List(Of Double)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Num As Double

    If listOfDouble.Count < 10 Then
        listOfDouble.Add(If(Double.TryParse(txtResult.Text, Num), Num, 0))
    Else
        txtResult.Text = "10 results already stored"
    End If
End Sub
```

And the you can iterate your list using For Each loop as:

```
Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    For Each doubleVal In listOfDouble
        listResults.Items.Add(doubleVal)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why would you want to fill  each element of the array with the same result? You need to persist the value of i between calls to `btnStore_Click`

Comment: With your code i will always be 0 when it hits the If statement so, you don't need the if at all. The value of txtResult.Text can't possibly change inside the For loop.

Answer (score 0):

I make sample of using List ( of T) to store, display and clear :

```
Dim ListDoube As New List(Of Double)

Private Sub btnStore_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStore.Click
    Dim Num As Double = 0

    If ListDoube.Count < 10 Then
        ListDoube.Add(If(Double.TryParse(txtResult.Text, Num), Num, 0))
    Else
        txtResult.Text = "10 results already stored"
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    For Each myVal In ListDoube
        lstResults.Items.Add(myVal.ToString)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    lstResults.Items.Clear()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will still use array:

```
Dim resultArray(9) As Double
Dim i As Integer = 0

Private Sub btnStore_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStore.Click
    Dim Num As Double = 0

    If i < 10 Then
        resultArray(i) = If(Double.TryParse(txtResult.Text, Num), Num, 0)
    Else
        txtResult.Text = "10 results already stored"

    End If
    i += 1
End Sub


Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    For Each myVal In resultArray
        lstResults.Items.Add(myVal.ToString)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    For myCnt = 0 To 9
        resultArray(myCnt) = 0
    Next
    lstResults.Items.Clear()
    i = 0
    txtResult.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, mostly.  The only issue now is that the results will always have a zero at the end of the list... not sure how to fix it. So if I input 2 entries, say 4+2 = 6 & 2+2 = 4, then the result array will have 6, 4, 0 in it.  Any ideas how to fix this?  Again, thanks for the support/help.

```
Public Shared resultArray(9) As Double
Public Shared i As Integer = 0

Protected Sub btnStore_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStore.Click

    If i >= 9 Then
        lblError.Text = "10 results already stored"
    Else
        lblError.Text = ""
        resultArray(i) = Convert.ToDouble(txtResult.Text)
        If i < 9 Then
            i += 1
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

    If i <= 0 Then
        lblError.Text = "You must add numbers"
    Else
        lstResults.Items.Clear()
        lblError.Text = ""
        For Num = 0 To i
            lstResults.Items.Add(resultArray(Num))
        Next Num
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Because your first index is 0, please try with -1, and you store data after incrementing index. So -1 Will indicate no data ini storage

Comment: Do what @user11982798 suggested and change `If i <= 0 Then` to `If i < 0 Then`  If i = 0 you have one entry in your array.